# Creating shortest path for a walk mode

Tags: python, postgis, pgrouting, network-analysis

I am new to `postgis` and `pgrouting`.

[image]

If you see the attached screenshot, I have loaded the osm data (currently I will be only talking about the walk mode).

Here we can see the two layers i.e. `multimodal_network`, and `multimodal_network_vertices_pgr`.

I have inspected the `multimodal_network_vertices_pgr` layer and loaded a path in red color which is not directed or connected to each other. However, We can still see the intersection b\w both points.

Now, I inspected another layer `multimodal_network` layer which has two circles representing point A and point B (did it intentionally to show).

If both lines are intersecting with each other then why they are not finding a path from point A to Point B?

I am using the following query to find the shortest path:

```
SELECT id, mode, ST_Distance(the_geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(4.3337174, 
   50.8364586), 4326)::geography) AS distance_m
   FROM (
     SELECT id, mode, the_geom, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mode ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(4.3337174, 50.8364586), 4326)) AS rank
    FROM multimodal_network_vertices_pgr
) subquery
WHERE rank = 1;


SELECT id, mode, ST_Distance(the_geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(4.3343012, 50.8370703), 4326)::geography) AS distance_m
FROM (
    SELECT id, mode, the_geom, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mode ORDER BY the_geom <-> ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(4.3343012, 50.8370703), 4326)) AS rank
    FROM multimodal_network_vertices_pgr
) subquery
WHERE rank = 1;
```

## Edit

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
            'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM multimodal_network WHERE mode = ''walk''',
            (SELECT id FROM <Id received from first query>),
            (SELECT id FROM <Id received from second query>),
            FALSE
        )
```

Here is the following on how I have created the topology

```
def create_topology(conn):
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    SELECT pgr_createTopology('multimodal_network', 0.00001, 'geometry', 'id', 'source', 'target', rows_where:='true', clean:=true);
""")
conn.commit()
create_topology(conn)


def update_vertices_with_mode(conn):
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""
    ALTER TABLE multimodal_network_vertices_pgr ADD COLUMN mode TEXT;
    UPDATE multimodal_network_vertices_pgr
    SET mode = subquery.mode
    FROM (
        SELECT id, mode FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (source, mode) source AS id, mode
            FROM multimodal_network
            UNION
            SELECT DISTINCT ON (target, mode) target AS id, mode
            FROM multimodal_network
        ) AS subquery
    ) AS subquery
    WHERE multimodal_network_vertices_pgr.id = subquery.id;
""")
conn.commit()
update_vertices_with_mode(conn)
```

The idea is to locate the nearest OpenStreetMap data for walk mode to the source and destination coordinates, and then find the shortest path between them.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't understand your shortest path query, why aren't you using pgr_dijkstra for instance?

Comment: @TimothyDalton my Bad! updated the query. The idea is to locate the nearest OpenStreetMap data for walk mode to the source and destination coordinates, and then find the shortest path between them.

Comment: So it looks like there is no vertex at that intersection hence it can't find a path. Can you visualise the nodes and confirm this?